# Return in recursive function doesn't exit function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am having hard time fixing my recursive function, which is a simplified tool for to scan DOM items and return matching element when found somewhere within document.

```
find: function(selector, element) {
    if(selector !== undefined) {
        if(element === undefined) {
            element = this.e;
        }
        var elements = element.childNodes;
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if(elements[i].nodeType === 1) {
                console.log(elements[i]);
                if(this.has_class(selector, elements[i]) === true) {
                    console.log('YAY, found it', elements[i]);
                    return elements[i];
                } else {
                    if(elements[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
                        this.find(selector, elements[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So the function should scan through children (and possibly their children) of given DOM element and return found element, otherwise go deeper and try again.

This is debuggable [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mqa9m9tj/).

As you can see in logs, it triggered console.log('found'); but it did not leave function returning it, but continue and eventually returned false (as of not found). How can it be fixed?

```js
var tools = {

  e: document.querySelector('.breadcrumbs'),

  has_class: function(name, element) {
    if (element.className === name) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },

  find: function(selector, element) {
    if (selector !== undefined) {
      if (element === undefined) {
        element = this.e;
      }
      var elements = element.childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].nodeType === 1) {
          console.log(elements[i]);
          if (this.has_class(selector, elements[i]) === true) {
            console.log('YAY, found it', elements[i]);
            return elements[i];
          } else {
            if (elements[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
              this.find(selector, elements[i]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

};

console.log(tools.find('test'));
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs" data-active="true">
  <div class="bc_navigation" onclick="events.bc_toggle(event, this);">
    <span class="bc_arrow"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bc_content">
    <div class="bc_wrapper">
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a onclick="events.go_home(event, this);">Landing</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a href="#prematch[prematch-sport][1|0|0|0|0]">Soccer</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a href="#prematch[prematch-group][1|4|0|0|0]">International</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a class="test" href="#prematch[prematch-event][1|4|16|10|0]">Int - World Cup</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a>Russia - Saudi Arabia</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return` exits the call to `find` where you found the element, but doesn't unwind all the calls that lead up to it.

Instead of

```
this.find(selector, elements[i]);
```

...in your `else`, you need to see if you got the element and, if so, return:

```
var result = this.find(selector, elements[i]);
if (result) {
    return result;
}
```

That lets it propagate up the chain.

Updated Live Example:

```js
var tools = {

  e: document.querySelector('.breadcrumbs'),

  has_class: function(name, element) {
    if (element.className === name) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  },

  find: function(selector, element) {
    if (selector !== undefined) {
      if (element === undefined) {
        element = this.e;
      }
      var elements = element.childNodes;
      for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].nodeType === 1) {
          console.log(elements[i]);
          if (this.has_class(selector, elements[i]) === true) {
            console.log('YAY, found it', elements[i]);
            return elements[i];
          } else {
            if (elements[i].childNodes.length > 0) {
              var result = this.find(selector, elements[i]);
              if (result) {
                return result;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

};

console.log(tools.find('test'));
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs" data-active="true">
  <div class="bc_navigation" onclick="events.bc_toggle(event, this);">
    <span class="bc_arrow"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bc_content">
    <div class="bc_wrapper">
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a onclick="events.go_home(event, this);">Landing</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a href="#prematch[prematch-sport][1|0|0|0|0]">Soccer</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a href="#prematch[prematch-group][1|4|0|0|0]">International</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a class="test" href="#prematch[prematch-event][1|4|16|10|0]">Int - World Cup</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a>Russia - Saudi Arabia</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is one of the key things about recursive functions: When they call themselves, they must look at the result of that call and propagate it when appropriate.

Comment: this is what i have been missing :) perfect thank you, as soon as i can i will accept this answer, this solves the problem, i was missing the check for attempting

Answer (score 1):

Result of the recursive call to `find` isn't processed. You should check to result value of the recursive call and should return its value when the recursive call located the element:

```
find: function(selector, element) {
    if(selector !== undefined) {
        if(element === undefined) {
            element = this.e;
        }
        var elements = element.childNodes;
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if(elements[i].nodeType === 1) {
                console.log(elements[i]);
                if(this.has_class(selector, elements[i]) === true) {
                    console.log('YAY, found it', elements[i]);
                    return elements[i];
                } else {
                    var foundElement = this.find(selector, elements[i]);
                    // *** Added this check to return the located element from the recursive call
                    if (foundElement != false) {
                        return foundElement;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**querySelector potential wasted**

Your `tools` library of functions is a good effort, but it shows a lack of understanding of how [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) actually works. To demonstrate my point, your entire program is rewritten below

```
// starting with the Document element, get the first child matching '.breadcrumbs'
const elem =
  document.querySelector ('.breadcrumbs')

// starting with `elem`, get the first child matching '.test'
const child =
  elem.querySelector ('.test')

console.log (child)
// <a class="test" href="#prematch[prematch-event][1|4|16|10|0]">Int - World Cup</a>
```

```js
const elem =
  document.querySelector ('.breadcrumbs')
  
const someChild =
  elem.querySelector ('.test')
  
console.log (someChild)
// <a class="test" href="#prematch[prematch-event][1|4|16|10|0]">Int - World Cup</a>
```

```html
<div class="breadcrumbs" data-active="true">
  <div class="bc_navigation" onclick="events.bc_toggle(event, this);">
    <span class="bc_arrow"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="bc_content">
    <div class="bc_wrapper">
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a onclick="events.go_home(event, this);">Landing</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a href="#prematch[prematch-sport][1|0|0|0|0]">Soccer</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a href="#prematch[prematch-group][1|4|0|0|0]">International</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a class="test" href="#prematch[prematch-event][1|4|16|10|0]">Int - World Cup</a>
      </div>
      <div class="step">
        <span class="dot"></span><a>Russia - Saudi Arabia</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**multiple classes**

Above, `querySelector` already does everything we need it to, but your `tools.has_class` exhibits another deficiency – elements can have more than one class. Your function would've skipped over a child that had an attribute `class="test foo"`.

For the sake of discussion, if you had to implement this on your own, you could adapt your `has_class` function to separate the element's classes by space, then check each class for a match – or you could use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which already includes a `contains` function

```js
const elem =
  document.querySelector ('.test')

console.log (elem.classList)
// { DOMTokenList [ "foo", "test", "bar" ] }

console.log (elem.classList.contains ('foo'))
// true

console.log (elem.classList.contains ('test'))
// true

console.log (elem.classList.contains ('dog'))
// false
```

```html
<div class="foo test bar"></div>
```